# How to change case dashboard column

Tags: civicase

We need to remove subject from case dashboard. we don't know where to change whether in report or in drupal. can any one please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

In sites/all/modules/civicrm/templates/CRM/Case/Page/DashboardSelector.tpl remove the line that starts with:

`<th data-data="subject"`

Also there is a similar line in sites/all/modules/civicrm/templates/CRM/Case/Form/ActivityTab.tpl

Comment: not able to find this path.. Is there any other path to get the file.

Comment: Are you using a file manager control panel? Does it have a search feature? Can you just do a file search for ActivityTab.tpl and DashboardSelector.tpl?